# Подскажите как сверстать данный элемент

Tags: html, css, css3, css-animation, позиционирование

Чтобы выводились при нажатии текст как у первого. Если можно - то ссылку на обучение этому

[image: Очень интересно, никогда не сталкивался с подобным]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть чудесный элемент `<label>`, который умеет переключать чекбокс внутри него. А еще в CSS есть селектор, определяющий - отмечен чекбокс или нет. Поэтому, всякому можно присвоить одно значение... а при клике на label, когда чекбокс переключится - переключить и остальное.

(в коде оставил только механизм. С "дизайном" уже сами сможете разобраться)

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/OPTlMUS/xfc7q3oa/)

```css
.flex {display: flex; background-color: #eee;}
/*Сам чекбокс, круглый минус и текст - изначально невидимы*/
.ch, .minus, .lorem {display: none;}
/*обеим дал круглый бордер*/
.plus, .minus {
  width: 16px; height: 16px; 
  border: 1px solid #333; border-radius: 50%; 
  text-align: center; }
.minus {border-color: red;}

/*когда чекбокс отмечен, происходит магия*/
.ch:checked ~ .flex {color: red;}
.ch:checked ~ .flex .plus {display: none;}
.ch:checked ~ .flex .minus {display: inline-block;}
.ch:checked ~ .lorem {display: block;}

.check {border: 1px solid #ddd; width: 500px; display: block; margin-bottom: 10px;}
```

```html
<label class="check">
  <input class="ch" type="checkbox">
  <div class="flex">
    <div class="minus">-</div>
    <div class="plus">+</div>
    <div class="title">1111</div>
  </div>
  <div class="lorem">1111</div>
</label>

<label class="check">
  <input class="ch" type="checkbox">
  <div class="flex">
    <div class="minus">-</div>
    <div class="plus">+</div>
    <div class="title">2222</div>
  </div>
  <div class="lorem">2222</div>
</label>
```

`.ch:checked ~ .flex` — подобная запись через волну означает "найти все элементы .flex, которые находятся где-то ниже в коде от класса .ch, но не обернуты в какой либо еще тег". А запись через пробел `.flex .minus` находит все .minus, которые находятся где-то внутри .flex.

В итоге `.ch:checked ~ .flex .minus {display: inline-block;}` подобная запись находит .minus, который находится во .flex, который находится где-то ниже .ch, который отмечен.

Если хочется открывая одну запись - сразу закрывать другую, надо будет подменить type="checkbox" на `type="radio"`

---

Но в целом... иногда CSS становится настолько сложным и запутанным, что нафиг его... легче записать пару строчек скрипта и не заморачиваться с километровым стилем. Вариант с JavaScript дает больше возможностей и не заставляет ограничивать разметку под CSS-селекторы → [JS-табы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/979232/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-js-%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA)