# Много css классов с тем же названием, как определить для каждого номер

Tags: javascript, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При нажатии на +, расскрываеться основаная часть блока, так как классы с тем же название, то нужно для каждого блока писать его порядковый номер.
К примеру `element[0].style.display = "block";`

Как это автоматизировать, при этом не писать для каждого собственную функцию.

```
var showInf = function showInf() {
    document.getElementsByClassName('style-main')[number].style.display = 'flex';

    plus[number].classList.add('rotate');

    plus[number].removeEventListener('click', showInf, false);
    plus[number].addEventListener('click', closeInf, false);
}

plus[number].addEventListener('click', showInf, false);

var closeInf = function closeInf() {
    document.getElementsByClassName('style-main')[number].style.display = 'none';

    plus[number].classList.remove('rotate');

    plus[number].addEventListener('click', showInf, false);
}
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/980669/Как-сделать-из-25-функций-одну/980679#980679 - Вчера как-раз отвечал про цикл for ))

Comment: А по вопросу "открыть-закрыть", возможно этот код поможет — https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/979232/Как-с-помощью-js-осуществить-изменение-текста-при-нажатии-определенных-кнопок/979287#979287